# How to merge two string columns where the one is subset of the other

Tags: python, string, pandas, search, merge

I have `DF1` and a `DF2` which i want to merge on the left side (on the `['text']` column)

The `DF2['text']` has some strings that are substrings of the `DF1['text']`.

I tried looping dirty with a double loop, but `DF1` is around 200k lines and `DF2` around 2k, so the time seems to be long ( best case scenario)

```py
DF1
id   text                           
1    'some text with details'       
2    'which are not always good'    
3    'irrelevant text'   
4    'I want to get rid of them'
5    'more irrelevant cells'

DF2
id   text                           tag
1    'with details'                 'Good'
2    'which are not'                'Bad'
3    'to get rid of'                'semiGood'
```

```py
for i in range(len(DF2)):
    for k in range(len(DF1)):
        if DF2['text'][i] in DF2['text'][k]:
            DF1.loc[:,'tag'].iloc[k] = DF2['tag'][i]
```

Expected output:

```py
DF1
id   text                           tag
1    'some text with details'       'Good'
2    'which are not always good'    'Bad'
3    'irrelevant text'              
4    'I want to get rid of them'    'semiGood'
5    'more irrelevant cells'
```

I would love to find a way to do this in less than 5 days that the double loop would require. Is there something?

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: Why didn't you merge both `df`s using `pandas.merge()` on `id`?

Comment: Because DF1 is 10 times larger and the common cells are spread across the column. I edited for a bit more clarity on that

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach is a little bit complex. You can try other techniques if you can find. This is my approach:

First, I split each word in column `text` from both `DF1` and `DF2`:

```
splitDF1, splitDF2 = [],[]
for i,tt1 in enumerate(DF1['text']):
    splitDF1.append([i,tt1.split()])
for i,tt2 in enumerate(DF2['text']):
    splitDF2.append([i,tt2.split()])
```

Then, I compare the list of splitted text in `DF1` with the one in `DF2`. If the splitted text in `DF2` is a subset of splitted text in `DF2`, store the `tag` into the new list, otherwise, leave it empty. Finally, add new column `tag` into `DF1` using the new list.

```
DF1tag = []
for sdf1 in splitDF1:
    for sdf2 in splitDF2:
        if set(sdf2[1]).issubset(sdf1[1]):
            tag = DF2.iloc[sdf2[0]][2]
            break
        else:
            tag = ""
    DF1tag.append(tag)
DF1['tag'] = DF1tag
```

Output:

```
print(DF1)

id                       text       tag
 1     some text with details      Good
 2  which are not always good       Bad
 3            irrelevant text          
 4  I want to get rid of them  semiGood
 5      more irrelevant cells
```